# Forwarding a Canadian number abroad?

Tags: cellphones, phone-networks

I have a Canadian and French phone number. Soon, I may also have a US phone number.

I'm looking for the cheapest way to keep all my phone numbers and have their calls and SMS forwarded to whatever number I'm using.

Right now, I'd like a cheap way to forward my calls and texts to my Canadian number over to my French one.

Any tips?

Comment: Port it to google voice.

Comment: If Google voice is not available, consider VoIP solutions e.g. voip.ms, twilio

Comment: I'd like to avoid google if possible.